# Amend Javascript code to Print,Tab & enter

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to java script, and I have to amend this code to make a product work...If I can't, may end sending it back.

I've tried amending the code very basically.Changed Tab to Enter, and back again.

```
function processData (arrData)
{
  var sData = DataToString(arrData);

  Print("Data: " + sData);
  if (!SendKeyStrokes (sData.replace(/\x00/g, " ") + "{TAB}"))
    NotifyWarning("Ignoring keystrokes sent to TWedge. Please set focus to the target application.");
}
```

This will output the bar code and tab over to next cell.
I'm hoping its easy, but I would like to amend it to do..

Code,tab,Code,tab,Code,tab,Code,Tab,Code,ENTER

Comment: What does `SendKeyStrokes` do? Is this something to do with google sheets or something?

Comment: I'm not 100% as its not mentioned anywhere else in the code I have. I think it might be the event I press the trigger on my scanner gun, it acts like a keyboard to the computer, but just takes the value of the barcode. Then I believe the sData bit and Tab are where the value is paste, and then Tab is pressed.

Comment: We're going to need a [mcve] here. It doesn't sound like you know what this does or how it does it, so obviously we know less than you do. As it stands, this question cannot be answered